# Open Adobe Reader when Desktop.open() is executed in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I execute my java code in ubuntu Desktop.open(pdf file) opens the Document Viewer instead of the Adobe Reader. I have modified the default program for application/pdf to be Adobe Reader. in the file /usr/share/applications/defaults.list. Also for a good measure right clicked on the file in Places and ensured the Adobe Reader is the default program.

Why does java not think so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I searched on ubuntu forums and solved the problem:

```
sethu@sethur-vostro:~$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
evince.desktop
sethu@sethur-vostro:~$ xdg-mime default acroread.desktop application/pdf
sethu@sethur-vostro:~$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
acroread.desktop
sethu@sethur-vostro:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

i used this:

```
try 
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("evince " + rutaPdfs);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "linux No  pude abrir evince");
    System.out.println("err al ejecutar evince (pdfs()):" + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Desktop.edit(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#edit%28java.io.File%29).